# Как получить данные из EditText в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `ExpandableListView`. В нем несколько парентов и в их айтемаx одна разметка, то есть одна разметка используется во всех вкладках. А в разметке несколько `EditText`.  Так вот мне нужно пройтись циклом по всем парентам потом по полям чтобы получить все данные с `EditText`. Но я Не понимаю где именно нужно писать какой метод использовать, без понятия. 
Нигде не нашел ответы по ExpandableListView, даже примеров нигде нету.
Вообще как получить данные при клике на bookClick?

Вот сам адаптер:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
String[] data;
public static EditText etBookingName;
public static EditText etBookingLastname;
public static EditText etBookingBirthday;
public static AutoCompleteTextView etBookingNationality;
public static Spinner spinner;
public static EditText etBookingPassport;
public static EditText etExpiryDate;
public static RadioGroup rgBookingGender;
public static boolean genderCheck = false;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View currentFocus = ((Activity)_context).getCurrentFocus();
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        currentFocus.clearFocus();
    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_list_items, null);

        etBookingNationality = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingNationality);
        etBookingName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingName);
        etBookingLastname = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingLastname);
        etBookingBirthday = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingBirthday);
        etBookingPassport = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingPassport);
        rgBookingGender = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rgBookingGender);
        etExpiryDate = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etDocumentExpiryDate);
          etBookingBirthday.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", etBookingBirthday));
        etExpiryDate.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", etExpiryDate));

            }
        });

        spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spDocument);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setPrompt("Title");
        spinner.setSelection(1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(_context, "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (this._listDataChild.containsKey(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)))
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_list_headers, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```

**Главный Активити:**

```
public class BookingActivity extends BaseActivity {

Button btnBook;
boolean isValid = true;

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

int adultPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.adultPassenger;
int childPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.childPassenger;
int babyPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.infPassenger;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.booking_layout);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.booking_title);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(80), width - GetPixelFromDips(20));
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(80), width - GetPixelFromDips(20));
    } else {
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(80), width - GetPixelFromDips(20));
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(80), width - GetPixelFromDips(20));
    }

    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    expListView.expandGroup(0);

    btnBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBooking);
    btnBook.setOnClickListener(bookClick);
}

public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> adult = null;
    List<String> child = null;
    List<String> baby = null;

    for (int i = 1; i <= adultPassCount; i++) {
        listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.adultPassengers) + " " + i);
        adult = new ArrayList<>();
        adult.add("Adult " + i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= childPassCount; i++) {
        listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.childPassengers) + " " + i);
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Child " + i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= babyPassCount; i++) {
        listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.infPassengers) + " " + i);
        baby = new ArrayList<>();
        baby.add("Baby " + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < adultPassCount; i++) {
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), adult);
    }

    if (childPassCount != 0) {
        for (int i = adultPassCount; i < adultPassCount + childPassCount; i++) {
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), child);
        }
    }
    if (babyPassCount != 0) {
        if (childPassCount != 0) {
            for (int i = adultPassCount + childPassCount; i < adultPassCount + childPassCount + babyPassCount; i++) {
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), baby);
            }
        }
        for (int i = adultPassCount; i < adultPassCount + babyPassCount; i++) {
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), baby);
        }
    }
}

View.OnClickListener bookClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listDataHeader.size(); i++) {
                expListView.expandGroup(i);
            }


    };
}
```